# Why does the first word get lost?

Tags: bash, pipe

Running the following command gave unexpected (to me) results.

```
(echo -n foo; sleep 4; echo bar) | while :; do read -t2 r; echo "###$r@@@"; done
###@@@
###@@@
###bar@@@
###@@@
...
```

I'm wondering where the "foo" went. I would it expect to be read by the first `read` call as a partial line. I would expect something like the following:

```
(echo -n foo; sleep 4; echo bar) | while :; do read -t2 r; echo "###$r@@@"; done
###foo@@@
###@@@
###bar@@@
###@@@
...
```

Since apparently this behavior (or it's documentation) has changed "recently" here is my bash version.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: What is `$BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: @Barmar Added to the question.

Comment: Same behavior in 4.4, `(echo -n foo; sleep 3) | (read -t r || echo "timeout: =$r=")` fails to output what should be a partial read. This could be a buffering issue and/or a bug.

Comment: @chepner, Yeah. After reading some of the responses I was starting to think that. Maybe I'll open a bug report and worst case the bash developers tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `-t` option says:

> Cause  `read`  to  time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within timeout seconds.

Since `foo` is echoed with no following newline, the first two `read`s can't read a complete line of input, so they time out and return failure. It doesn't assign the partial input to `$r`, and just discards it.

The third `read` succeeds because `bar` is followed by a newline, so that's read as a complete line.

The above is from `bash` versions prior to 4.3. What you've written seems like it's supposed to work in 4.3+, I'm not sure why it still behaves as the older version.

Comment: Really? My bash man page says "If read times out, read saves any partial input read into the specified variable name."

Comment: I see that in the bash 4.3 manual at www.gnu.org. But I don't see it in the man page for 4.2.37 on my Debian server, or 3.2.48 on my OS X box.

Comment: Not sure what bash you're using but I see "-t <timeout> Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within timeout seconds. " http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: @Mort It's in http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Comment: The man page for 4.4 does indicate that `read` will assign partially read input to its argument(s) in the event of a timeout.

Comment: Your tag is [bash]. Bourne Shell is sh. bash is Bourne *Again* Shell It's the next page. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: Sorry, just copied the wrong link from the contents page. But the point is that it's in the Bash Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Lets analyze your command:

#### Echo

The part of echo, simply outputs foobar.
It just happens that foo goes out at a different time than bar:

```
$ (echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar)
foobar
$ (echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar) | cat
foobar
```

#### Read

The read part just gets that output in a variable:

```
$ (echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar) | { read -t2 r; echo "###$r@@@"; }
###foobar@@@
```

If the sleep time if bigger than the read timeout time, read gets nothing:

```
$ (echo -n foo; sleep 4; echo bar) | { read -t2 r; echo "###$r@@@"; }
###@@@
```

#### While (many lines).

With a while, read is repeated. some number of reads get all the all the input and then, after the pipe is closed, read gets EOF immediately (it doesn't wait for a timeout when this happens). It returns an error when this happens, but nothing is checking whether read got an error, so the loop repeats.

So: Many lines get created:

```
$ (echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar) |
{ while :; do read -t2 r; echo "###$r@@@"; done; }
```

We can redirect the output to a file (testfile.txt) and also, We can control how long that works with this (split on three lines for readability) (the `>` are not part of the command):

```
$ { echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar; } | { 
> while :; do read -t2 r; echo "###$r@@@"; \
> done; } > testfile.txt & sleep 2; kill $!
[1] 28541
[1]+  Terminated  ....
```

Now we can see how many lines got written:

```
$ wc -l testfile.txt
35543 testfile.txt
```

That means that about 35k lines get written to the file per second.
The number after the last sleep (before the kill) has to be bigger than the number on the first sleep or no lines get written to the file.

#### Which lines:

And which of those are **not** a repetition of `###@@@`:

```
$ grep -vn "^###@@@"
1:###foobar@@@
```

So, only the first line of the file actually contains information, the rest is a continuous repetition of `###@@@`.

## Sleep less than read -t

That is what happen if the sleep time (1) is lower than the read timeout (2). A 1 for sleep, a 2 for read.

## Sleep longer than read -t

If we make the time of sleep longer than the read timeout:

```
$ a=3; b=2; c=5
$ { echo -n foo; sleep $a; echo bar; } | { 
> while :; do read -t$b r; echo "###$r@@@"; \
> done; } > testfile.txt & sleep $c; kill $!
[1] 29032
[1]+  Terminated ........

$ wc -l testfile.txt
65226 testfile.txt                      ### Again ~ 30 k per second.
$ grep -vn "^###@@@" testfile.txt
2:###bar@@@
```

## Conclusion?

What seems to be happening is that after the echo have written their output, the while keeps repeating reads that receive an "empty" input, and that is written to the file (as many ###@@@ lines).

Only when the first echo sleep longer (a=3) that the first read timeout (b=2) is that we get a division in two different lines of `foo` and `bar`.

That seems to say that `foo` goes out at time 0, the first read times out without a full line having been received and emits an initial `###@@@` (eating the `foo` without output?). Then the `bar` comes with an ending newline to the second read, and this read emits a `###bar@@@`. As the left side of the pipe has terminated, read keeps producing empty lines.

If the sleep is 4 and the timeout is 2, (from your question)the timeout may happen twice, and two lines may be written to the output. That will make the `bar` line the third (two timeouts, next the bar line), but that is not a guarantee, as two sleeps are controlling this, and they may wander a bit.

After all the output from the left side of the pipe has been emitted. The read is receiving many "empty lines"???. Which get written to the file and we get to analyze them.

## some loose issues.

#### Static (no while) reads.

We can make a much more specific command to analyze:

```
$ { echo 'foo'; sleep 3; echo 'bar'; } |
  { read -t1 r; echo "read r value=|$r|"; \
    read -t1 s; echo "read s value=|$s|"; }
read r value=|foo|
read s value=||
```

If the sleep (3) is longer than the reads, only the first `foo` is read.

```
$ { echo 'foo'; sleep 1; echo 'bar'; } |
  { read -t2 r; echo "read r value=|$r|"; \
    read -t2 s; echo "read s value=|$s|"; }
read r value=|foo|
read s value=|bar|
```

With a longer read timeout allowance for input to appear, both `foo` and `bar` get read.

#### While

If we include a simple while:

```
{ echo -n foo; sleep 4; echo bar; } | {
    while read -t2 r; do
    echo "###$r@@@";
done;
}
```

Only for an sleep lower than the read timeout we never get output: the full foobar.
If the sleep is longer than the read timeout: the first read fails, has an exit code of 1 and that exit  the while.

That's why we get to an infinite while. But that needs a file and a final timeout, in code:

```
a=3; b=2; c=5
{ echo -n foo; sleep $a; echo bar; } | {
    while :; do
    read -t$b r;
    echo "###$r@@@";
done;
} > testfile.txt & sleep $c; kill $!

wc -l testfile.txt; grep -vn "^###@@@" testfile.txt
```

Comment: The reason for the infinite `while` is because after the 2nd `echo` the pipe is closed, so `read` gets EOF immediately (it doesn't wait for a timeout when this happens). It returns an error when this happens, but nothing is checking whether `read` got an error, so the loop repeats.

Comment: The basic problem is that there's no way to distinguish a timeout from some other error.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar tried to include both of your comments (but please leave them) they are useful as they stand.

Answer (score -1):

If you take out the `-t 2` you will see it capture `foobar`. Does that give you enough of a hint?

You have chosen to echo 'foo' without a return at the end of the line, but `read` is waiting for a CR to trigger it. That does not happen with `foo` so read simply times out twice waiting to get anything. Then when 'bar\n' is echoed, it does contain a CR so `read` picks it up.

**Update**
I had been looking at documentation for an older version of bash. The original question was since updated to include the bash version. As noted, it seems as if the bash documentation has changed, but the actual behaviour has not and that there is perhaps a bash bug involved.

The pre-4.3 documentation indicates that on timeout, an error will be raised, but does not indicate if any buffered input will be read into the next variable or not. The 4.3 documentation says "If read times out, read saves any partial input read into the specified variable name."

Many of my comments on this thread are incorrect, based on this new information.

Comment: But the question is why doesn't the next call of `read` pick up the "foo". It just seems to get lost in the void somewhere. Furthermore I would expect the first call to pick it up because it should be written before the timeout is up.

Comment: Yes, it just gets dropped. As I said in my comment, if you take out '-t 2' and don't force it to timeout and taking what it's got (nothing) then you won't lose the 'foo'. Or if you replace it with '-n 3', just because. Play with it interactively, replacing your `(...)` with `cat |` and type stuff on the terminal.

Comment: I'm not following your logic. If it has nothing how can it drop the "foo"? And if it has read the "foo" it won't have nothing.

Comment: It hasn't read the foo. It timed out before a CR was ever sent and foo was lost.

Comment: Before a newline (which is what I presume you mean by CR) is read or before any input is read?

Answer (score -4):

Try

```
... | while read a
do
    ...
done
```

I think maybe the dummy command ':' take the input.

Comment: The `:` command doesn't read any input. You're just making things up.

Comment: It was a maybe :p and I found strange not to use read as looping command to handle errors

Comment: If you use `read` as the looping command, the loop stops when the read times out.

Comment: Couldn't you just read the documentation of the `:` command to see if it reads any input? It's pretty clear, it says it doesn't do anything except expand variables in its arguments.

Comment: Could you be more polite it's a collaboration space. Bad guesses are helping too cause they eliminate wrong path ... So plz keep it down

Comment: @quazardous Bad guesses that can easily be eliminated by a little research are just noise.